# Returning a raw value from an Array in Swift (rather than an ArraySlice)

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to do something that should be very simple. I have an array of Dates and from this I simply want to extract a Date from a given index.

In Python I could do something like this:
`print(type(myArray[i]`
and it would come back with some kind of Date type.

However when I grab a value from my array in Swift it won't accept it as a Date input for my next function because its type is ArraySlice.

My question is simply this - how can I 'unwrap' my ArraySlice and actually get the Date object inside?

```
var cycleStartsArr: Array<Date> = Array()

// Some code that puts dates into the array

  var gaps: Array<Int> = Array() // Will contain list of the gaps in days
   
    for i in [1..<cycleStartsArr.count] {
        let startDate = cycleStartsArr[i]
        let endDate = cycleStartsArr[i-1]
        let gap = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate.day!, to:endDate.day! // Throws Cannot convert value of type 'ArraySlice<Date>' to expected argument type 'Date'.
        gaps.append(gap)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
[1..<cycleStartsArr.count]
```

is an array ***OF*** range***S***.

You meant

```swift
cycleStartsArr.indices.dropFirst()
```

Or better yet,

```swift
import Algorithms

for (endDate, startDate) in cycleStartsArr.adjacentPairs() {
```